# IOException caused by file being in use

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem that I know people already asked here but I tried the solution they bring but it's not helping.

My problem: I'm doing a program in C# with 2 forms. My main form is used to read a file .txt and put the information in a DataGridView:

```
public void LireFichier()
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

        string delimeter = ";";
        string tableName = "Clients";
        string filePath = @"C:...\Clients.txt";

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            dataset.Tables.Add(tableName);
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("ID");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("Name");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("LastName");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("Datet");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("Price");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("Phone");
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("ID box");

            string allData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] rows = allData.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

            foreach (string r in rows)
            {
                string[] items = r.Split(delimeter.ToCharArray());
                dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items);
            }
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
         }
```

My second form is used to add a client in my .txt file :

```
      private void btn_Confirmer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        string filePath = @"...\Clients.txt";
        Client client = new Client();

        client.Id = idClient++;
        client.Name = tb_name.Text;
        client.LastName = tb_lastName.Text;

        client.Date = dtp_date.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        client.Price = Convert.ToInt32(tb_price.Text);
        client.Phone = tb_telephone.Text;
        client.ID_Box = Convert.ToInt32(tb_idbox.Text);

        string clientInfo = client.Id.ToString() + ";" + client.Name.ToString() + ";" + client.LastName.ToString() + ";" + client.Date.ToString() + ";" +
                            client.Montant.ToString() + ";" + client.Phone.ToString() + ";" + client.ID_Boc.ToString() + ";";

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string allData = sr.ReadToEnd() + clientInfo;
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, allData);
        }

        this.Close();
      }
```

The problem remains in the StreamReader or the File.WriteAllText no matter what I do I always encounter the same exception(System.IO.IOException) that my file is in use when I arrived to write(add a client) in the file in my second form.

The solution that I tried are:

1. put the using blocks
2. sr.Close()
3. sr.Dispose() even if I know that the using block call dispose at the end.
4. sr.Close() and sr.Dispose() at the end of the instruction.

Comment: Is there a chance that these blocks are running in same time? I mean while file is red an attempt to write is performed, which results in throwing exception

Comment: Start by giving us the actual exception text

Comment: What I do is I call function ReadFile(); in my public form1(){} before InitializeComponent(); where I read my file then close my file (atleast I tried to close) and I have another button_click That open my second form where I can add a client

Comment: my exception is in french il try to translate;
An exception non-handled 'System.IO.IOException' has being encounter in mscorlib.dll

 
more information : the process cant acces to the file 'C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\GestionClientPix\GestionClientPix\Clients.txt', because it's already used.

Comment: Please indicate in your code where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to the following since I think the write is interfering with the read you are already performing.

```
string allData; 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    allData = sr.ReadToEnd() + clientInfo;
}

this.Close();
File.WriteAllText(filePath, allData);
```

Comment: `allData` is defined within the scope of the `using` block and can't be used outside

Comment: Yeah I saw too late, but the editing of the code block has been interesting :p It should declare allData before the using, but for whatever reason the code block won't show that line. There it goes ... sort of.

Comment: Ok I tried you code and I can reproduce the exception exactly as you describe in the original post.  When I tried my changes, the issue was resolved. And I agree with Alexi about the way to handle the exceptions, and also that you only need to append to the file with the client info, no need to rewrite all of it.

Comment: yeah I tried it on my program and it resolve the problem thank yoo!

Comment: Use `File.AppendText(path, text)` instead. (Or variants)

Answer (score 1):

`Trelly` indicated the most possible cause of you problem (file already in use). However, the solution containing exception handling should look like this:

```
try 
{
    string allData = null; 
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        allData = sr.ReadToEnd() + clientInfo;
    }

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, allData);
}
catch (IOException exc)
{
    // exception handling code
}

this.Close();
```

**OR**

It looks like you want to just append some text at the end of the file. [File.AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is your friend:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath)) 
{
    sw.Write(clientInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you !I don't have the error when use the AppendText it means the problem was when i use 2 streamreader for the same file

Answer (score 0):

To make your blocks of code `thread safe`, I would use a `lock` statement. 
First declare object, you will perform lock on:

```
public static readonly Object Locker = new Object();
```

Then surround your parts of code, where you are working with file with lock statement:

```
lock(Locker)
{
   //perform file operations
}
```

Remember that both forms have to refer to the same Locker object

Answer (score 0):

After ReadToEnd, close the StreamReader before WriteAllText:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string allData = sr.ReadToEnd() + clientInfo;
    sr.Close() ; // <---- add this instruction
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, allData);
}
```